# how to serialize properly in perticular format

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Please help me improve my code.. im newly placed and learning things

i want to display separately product field in my code  just like category and sub-category in my code but i don't know how to. Also please point out if there anything that i can improve in my code

> Here is my output:

```
[
    {
        "Category": {
            "c_id": 1,
            "parent_id": 15
        },
        "Sub_category": {
            "sc_id": 1,
            "is_active2": 1
        },
        "p_id": 2,
        "group_id": "",
        "product_name": "Fruit",
        "is_prescription_needed": 1, 
}]
```

> Whereas my expected format is:

```
[
    {
        "Category": {
            "c_id": 1,
            "parent_id": 15
        },
        "Sub_category": {
            "sc_id": 1,
            "is_active2": 1
        },
        "Product":  {                    # How do i separate this "Product" key and value
            "p_id": 2,
            "group_id": "",
            "product_name": "Fruit",
            "is_prescription_needed": 1
}]
```

here is my code:

> Serialziers.py

```
class ProductCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    c_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    category_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        fields = ["c_id","parent_id","category","category_image","is_active"]
        model = Category
    def get_c_id(self,obj):
        return obj.id
    def get_category_image(self,obj):
        return obj.image

class ProductSubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sc_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_active2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        fields = ["sc_id","sub_category","is_active2"]
        model = ProductSubCategory
    def get_sc_id(self,obj):
        return obj.id
    def get_is_active2(self,obj):
        return obj.is_active

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Category = ProductCategorySerializer(source='category', read_only=True)
    Sub_category = ProductSubCategorySerializer(source='sub_category', read_only=True)
    product_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    p_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["Category","Sub_category", "p_id", "group_id", "product_name", "is_prescription_needed",
              "product_description", "product_keypoint", "product_type", "product_image", "pack", "pack_unit", "hsn",
              "company", "brand_id", "composition", "drug_details", "uses",
              "side_effects", "cope_side_effects", "how_it_works", "safety_advice", "what_if_forget",
              "medical_constraints", "created_at", "created_by", "modified_at", "modified_by"]
        model = Product

    def get_product_image(self, obj: Product):
        image = obj.image
        if len(image) == 0:
            return ""
        return image

    def get_p_id(self,obj):
        return obj.id
```

> View.py

```
class categoryProduct(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def post(self, request):
        params = request.query_params
        category = params.get("category")
        sub_category = params.get("sub_category")
        kwargs = {}
        if category:
            kwargs['category'] = category
        else:
            kwargs['category'] = 1

        if sub_category:
            kwargs['sub_category'] = sub_category
        else:
            kwargs['sub_category'] = 1
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(**kwargs)
        all_response = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        #AFTER PAGINATION
        return Response(all_response)
```

> models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='category')
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductSubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='sub_category')
    group_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    is_prescription_needed = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'product'


class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    store_image = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    parent_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'category'

class ProductSubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="category")
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_active = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sub_category'
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant models here as well?

Comment: updated my post with models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a separate field that is a a SerializerField of a serializer you create with the proper fields you want displayed under the `Product` key. This is how your other field, like `Category` get appropriately created. That is to say: remove the fields from the `ProductSerializer` into a new serializer, then add a `Product` SerializerField with the new serializer containing those keys.

One other way you can do this is to create a `.to_representation` method to change the output to precisely the format you want.

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['Product'] = {
            "p_id": representation.pop('p_id')
            "group_id": representation.pop('group_id'),
            "product_name": representation.pop('product_name'),
            "is_prescription_needed": representation.pop('is_prescription_needed')
        }
        return representation
```